# CSS file not loading for specific folder name

Tags: html, css, apache, filenames

I created a simple html file index.html and a css file style.css.
In the head of html i got:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
```

Both files are in the same folder, called "zedo_template_new" on my localhost.
But when i visit http://localhost/zedo_template_new/index.html the css file is not loaded.

The crazy thing is, if i rename the folder to "edo_template_new" and visit http://localhost/edo_template_new/index.html the css file is loaded and everything works fine!

It seems that any name except "zedo_template_new" is working (i tried about 20 different names, all worked).

Additional, i can observe this behaviour on any webspace i upload this folder.
What the heck is going on here? And how can i make my Apache to load css files for every folder name?

Thx for help

Comment: I'd check the .htaccess

Comment: Could it be that you have some software for blocking ad / tracking cookie / spyware. Zedo is an ad company with tracking cookies and similar. May be a false positive from this software?

Comment: hey @Zimmi you were right! I restarted firefox without addons and it works correctly! thanks for your help!

Comment: Still I'm a bit surprised that this guess came out to be right :-), but good to know it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by @Zimmi:
My Ad blocker was blocking it because of the "Zedo" ad company.